# HTML Pagination Parsing with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I am trying to parse movie website with pagination. I want to parse all movie items on page 1 and when it will be done I want parser to continue on next page. I wrote a parser which works but it does not parses all movie items on page and do not continue on another page.  I want to detect when parsing of one result is done and make it move on next item. Then detect when all movie items are parsed and make it move on next page. I expect that when I run parser, it should display movie title, year, etc. one by one and then continue on next page. Currently it only displays/parsing only one movie item on page 1 and do not continues work. Here's my code and example:

Parsing Example: http://minerbitco.in/parse/parse.php

```
    <?php

    include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';



    $page = (!isset($_GET['page'])) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
        echo '<br> Parsing Page #'.$page.'<br><br>';
        $html = file_get_html('https://srulad.com/movies/type/movie#page-'.$page);
        $obj = $html->find('div.movie_item');
        $datas = [];
        if($obj){
            foreach ($obj as $key => $data) {


                $movie_url = 'https://srulad.com/'.$data->find('div.poster a', 0)->href;

                $html2 = file_get_html($movie_url);

                $item['url'] = $movie_url;

                $item['year'] = $html2->find('#movie_content > div', 0)->children(2)->find('div', 0)->children(0)->children(1)->plaintext;

                $item['genre'] =  $html2->find('#movie_content > div', 0)->children(1)->find('span', 0)->plaintext;

                $item['description'] = $html2->find('#movie_content > div', 0)->children(1)->find('div.plot', 0)->plaintext;

                $item['imdb_rating'] = $html2->find('#movie_content > div', 0)->children(2)->find('div', 0)->children(1)->children(1)->find('span', 0)->plaintext;

                $item['englishtitle'] = $html2->find('#movie_content > div', 0)->children(1)->find('h2.newmt', 0)->plaintext;

                $item['geotitle'] = $html2->find('#movie_content > div', 0)->children(1)->find('h3.newmt', 0)->plaintext;

                $item['poster'] = $html2->find('#movie_content > div', 0)->children(0)->find('img', 0)->src;



                $url = $item['url'];
                $year = $item['year'];
                $desc = $item['description'];
                $rating = $item['imdb_rating'];
                $poster = $item['poster'];
                $engtitle = $item['englishtitle'];
                $geotitle = $item['geotitle'];
                $genre = $item['genre'];
    }}

if ($data === end($obj)) {
    echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=#page-'.($page+1).'">';
}

else {
    echo "dasrulebulia.";
}

    echo 'URL: '.$url.'<br>';
    echo 'პოსტერის URL: '.$poster.'<br>';
    echo 'სათაური ინგლისურად: '.$engtitle.'<br>';
    echo 'სათაური ქართულად: '.$geotitle.'<br>';
    echo 'წელი:'.$year.'<br>';
    echo 'ჟანრი:'.$genre.'<br>';
    echo 'აღწერა:'.$desc.'<br>';
    echo 'რეიტინგი:'.$rating.'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I wonder what is wrong in my code. I expect that when I run parser, it should display movie title, year, etc. one by one and then continue on next page. Currently it only displays/parsing only one movie item on page 1 and do not continues work.

Comment: You keep overwriting `$url` and co. at every cycle. How do you expect them to *not* show just one result at a time?

Comment: How can I detect when parsing of one result is done and make it move on next item? Then detect when all movie items are parsed and make it move on next page?

Answer (score 0):

you can give it a try to Parser i have written:

https://github.com/sachinsinghshekhawat/simple-html-dom-parser-php

Comment: And how will I be able to detect when parsing of one result is done and make it move on next item. Then detect when all movie items are parsed and make it move on next page with your parser?